# Create generic interface class in C++

Tags: c++, abstraction, factory-method

I need your help.  
 A have some classes, you can see it on my code. Archer, Footman, Knight...that are based on Unit class. 
 And I also have a Two Factory , that will create a new objects ( Humans and Orks ).
Now I need to create generic interface class "Сombat Squad" which will contain a lot of different units that will be generated by random. And methods like attack or go should work for all of units.
I hope you understand what I mean, My English is so bad, and this is my first time when I ask for help internationally D.

```
class Unit {
public:
    virtual void description() = 0;
    virtual void attack() = 0;
    virtual void go() = 0;
    virtual ~Unit() {}
};

//Human
class Archer : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Archer" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Archer attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Archer go" << endl;
    }
};

class Footman : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Footman" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Footman attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Footman go" << endl;
    }
};
class Knight : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Knight" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Knight attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Knight go" << endl;
    }
};

//Ork
class Spearman : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Spearman" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Spearman attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Spearman go" << endl;
    }
};

class Grunt : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Grunt" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Grunt attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Grunt go" << endl;
    }
};
class Wolfrider : public Unit {
    void description() override {
        cout << "Wolfrider" << endl;
    }
    void attack() override {
        cout << "Wolfrider attack" << endl;
    }
    void go() override {
        cout << "Wolfrider go" << endl;
    }
};

class Factory {
public:
    virtual Unit* createMelee() = 0;
    virtual Unit* createRanged() = 0;
    virtual Unit* createMounted() = 0;
    virtual ~Factory() {}
};

class Barracks : public Factory {
public:
    virtual Unit* createMelee(){
        return new Footman();
    }
    virtual Unit* createRanged(){
        return new Archer();
    }
    virtual Unit* createMounted() {
        return new Knight();
    }
};

class Layer : public Factory {
public:
    virtual Unit* createMelee(){
        return new Grunt();
    }
    virtual Unit* createRanged(){
        return new Spearman();
    }
    virtual Unit* createMounted() {
        return new Wolfrider();
    }
};

int main() {
    Factory* f = new Barracks();
    //Layer f;

    vector<Unit*> army;
    army.push_back(f->createMelee());
    army.push_back(f->createMelee());
    army.push_back(f->createRanged());
    army.push_back(f->createRanged());
    army.push_back(f->createMounted());

    for(auto unit : army){
        unit->description();
        unit->attack();
        unit->go();
    }
    for(auto unit : army)
        delete unit;
    army.clear();
    delete f;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Consider the use of [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) instead of handling raw pointers.

Comment: Your factory seems close to the CombatSquad you want (but it doesn't need to be a pointer) - is the trouble the random part?

Comment: Yes,  I dont understand how CombatSquad will work with Units. Should the list of Units be a CombatSquad  class field? And in this case, how will I generate different types of units and put all of them to the CombatSquad.  Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the code attached it seems you are searching for the *[Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern#Structure)*!
In this case, your *CombatSquad* class should contain a collection of *Unit* (s) and forward the request to the units, defining the operation of the base class as performing the same operation for each child.
Take this snippet as an example of what I mean:

```
class CombatSquad: public Unit{
private:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Unit>> squad;

public:
void attack() override {
  for(auto& unit : squad)
     unit.attack()
}
// similarly for the other methods

void add(std::shared_ptr<Unit> unit){
  squad.push_back(unit)
}
}
```

You can use the `add` method to compose your squad, using maybe your factories to generate the different units you need.